# Error when recording sound on Pepper robot

Tags: python, python-2.7, nao-robot, pepper

I want my Pepper robot to record a piece of audio using `startMicrophonesRecording()`. In [NAOqi v2.5](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/alaudiorecorder-api.html) it takes four arguments (path, type, hertz and microphones). Trying to run

```
AD.startMicrophonesRecording("/data/home/nao/recordings/microphones/test.wav","wav",16000,(0,0,1,0))
```

I however get the error message

```
RuntimeError: Arguments types did not match for startMicrophonesRecording (resolved to '(ssi(iiii))'): 
Candidate: 
  startMicrophonesRecording::(s) (1)
```

It seems that `startMicrophonesRecording()` only wants one argument. I can see in [past versions](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-0/naoqi/audio/alaudiodevice-api.html#ALAudioDeviceProxy::startMicrophonesRecording__ssCR) of the function that it used to only take the file path as an argument, so maybe Python is looking at a past version of NAOqi for the modules?

I have tried setting `PYTHONPATH` to `C:\Users\<user>\<path>\pynaoqi-python2.7-2.5.5.5-win32-vs2013\lib` using [this tutorial](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/python/install_guide.html#python-install-guide), but I still get the same error.

Any ideas as to what I can do?

Python 2.7 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try with one argument?

The [NAOqi v2.5 Link](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/alaudiorecorder-api.html) you named, refers to **ALAudioRecorder** and C++.
The "old Version" refers to Python **ALAudioDevice**.
An NAOqi v2.5 Python API for **ALAudioDevice** is described [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/alaudiodevice-api.html#ALAudioDeviceProxy::startMicrophonesRecording__ssCR).

For me these python snippets works fine:

**ALAudioDevice**:

```
import naoqi
from naoqi import ALProxy
AD = ALProxy("ALAudioDevice", "pepper.local", 9559)
AD.startMicrophonesRecording("/data/home/nao/recordings/microphones/test.wav")
AD.stopMicrophonesRecording()
```

**ALAudioRecorder**:

```
import naoqi
from naoqi import ALProxy
AR = ALProxy("ALAudioRecorder", "pepper.local", 9559)
AR.startMicrophonesRecording("/data/home/nao/recordings/microphones/test.wav","wav",16000,[0,0,1,0])
AR.stopMicrophonesRecording()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for selecting microphones looks wrong.
Use brackets [] instead of parentheses ():

```
    rec = self.session().service("ALAudioRecorder")
    rec.startMicrophonesRecording(fname, 'wav', 16000, [0,0,1,0])
```